# GraphicsMagick++ draw text and auto-resize canvas

Tags: graphicsmagick, magick++

I am planning to generate an image with Magick (GraphicsMagick++) that have some text and I want the image canvas resized automatically based on the text drawn.

This is my code:

```
    bool LoadText(const std::string& text, const std::string& fontface, int pointsize, Magick::Color color) {

    image = Magick::Image( Magick::Geometry(1,1), Magick::Color("black"));
    image.font(fontface);
    image.fillColor(color);
    image.strokeColor(color);
    image.fontPointsize(pointsize);
    image.read("CAPTION:" + text);
    //image.annotate(text,CenterGravity);
    return true;
}
```

With "annotate()" the canvas is not resized but the text color and background is right.

If I use "CAPTION:" protocol the canvas is resized but the fontcolor and background color is not respected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to allocated a blank image when reading from the caption protocol, but set the background color directly.

```cpp
using namespace Magick;

bool LoadTextCaption(const std::string& text,
                     const std::string& fontface,
                     int pointsize,
                     Magick::Color color)
{
    Image image;                           // Allocated but not initialized.
    image.font(fontface);
    image.fillColor(color);
    image.strokeColor(color);
    image.fontPointsize(pointsize);
    image.backgroundColor(Color("BLACK")); // <- Set background
    image.read("CAPTION:" + text);
    return true;
}
// ... 
LoadTextCaption("Hello Caption!", "TimesNewRoman", 32, Color("RED"));
```

[image: Hello Caption!]

Comment: Thanks I will try it. But I have one question regarding your sample. Why the text is drawn in 2 lines. I want the text in just one line.

Comment: I get the following runtime error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Magick::ErrorOption'
  what():  Magick: Must specify image size (Hello Caption!) reported by coders/caption.c:110 (ReadCAPTIONImage)
Magick: abort due to signal 6 (SIGABRT) "Abort"...